# Share proprietary Nvidia Drivers with chroot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, chroot

Is it possible to allow my chroot to use the same Nvidia Drivers as my host os?
Drivers are proprietary / not included in the Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

The proprietary Nvidia driver consists of multiple parts:

- kernel modules: `nvidia-drm.ko`, `nvidia.ko`, `nvidia-modeset.ko`, and in newer versions, also `nvidia-peermem.ko` and `nvidia-uvm.ko`. If DKMS is used, these can be found in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms/`. Since a chroot uses the same kernel as the host OS, you don't need to copy these into a chroot.
- some utilities in `/usr/lib/nvidia/`
- some utilities in `/usr/bin/nvidia-*`
- a number of OpenGL, OpenCL and VDPAU libraries in `/usr/lib[64]/` or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, depending on distribution
- configuration file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia-drm-outputclass.conf`
- an X.org X11 server driver in `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so` (or wherever your distribution places the X server driver modules)
- an X.org X11 server extension module in `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/libglxserver_nvidia.so*` (or wherever your distribution places the X server extension modules)

Unless you run a separate hardware-accelerated X server (and thus a separate physical display) for your chroot, you'll only need the libraries and maybe the utilities, depending on what the chroot is actually for.

You can certainly copy (or perhaps `mount --bind`) the libraries and the utilities into your chroot. I'd recommend writing a script or a Makefile to handle the actual copying, to make it easier to re-copy things into the chroot after a driver update.